# Monitoring available bandwidth on my network

Tags: networking, bandwidth, monitoring

I was wondering if there is a way to monitor the total bandwidth available at any given time? My ISP claims and is charging me for a certain amount of bandwidth but I suspect that during the day I am getting much less.

I would like to track available bandwidth continuously (or every 5, 10, 15 minutes) and log that data so I can show them the results.

I'm on a Mac 10.7 but can use Windows XP also.

Comment: You mean bandwidth as in available megabits per second?  The only way you could realistically do that would be to download something periodically that would saturate your link, and measure how fast it went.  It is doable, but you'd have to ensure nothing else was on the link at the time, so it doesn't sound feasible.

Comment: Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle will apply here: By observing the available bandwidth, you will change the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do scheduled speed tests with the online service [testmy.net/auto](http://testmy.net/auto).

> This will automatically retest your Internet connection on a set interval and log the test results for later retrieval. The Automatic Speed Test can provide data that may aid in Internet troubleshooting. Simply set the test interval, click start and forget about it. Then, come back later and retrieve your results. TMN requires only your web browser, has trusted test results and is always free. As an added convenience registered members get an email reminder when the test is finished.

[image]